# How to suppress error text with Get-DhcpServerv4Lease

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script to look through an IP range in DHCP and report all the addresses that don't have leases.  There's a function that supposedly does this already, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

In any case, what I'm looking to understand is why the following code doesn't catch errors:

```
for ($x = 2; $x -le 255; $x++)
{
    $ip = "172.30.218.$x"

    try
    {
        Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -IPAddress $ip -computername servername | out-null
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output $ip
    }
}
```

I keep getting this instead:

Get-DhcpServerv4Lease : Failed to get lease information for IPAddress 172.30.218.255 from DHCP server servername.

I have a workaround, but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Workaround also has the awful red text, but at least I collect the ips I'm interested in when I redirect it to a file:

```
for ($x = 2; $x -lt 255; $x++)
{
    $ip = "172.30.218.$x"

    $temp = $null
    $temp = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -IPAddress $ip -computername servername
    if ($temp -eq $null) { Write-Output $ip }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847793.aspx):

> SHORT DESCRIPTION
>
> Describes how to use the Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to handle terminating errors.

Only terminating errors can be caught. You can make PowerShell treat *non*-terminating errors as a terminating error with `-ErrorAction Stop`. This will `catch` the error and run the block as expected. Note this only affects the behavior of errors from `Get-DhcpServer4Lease`. You could specify `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of your script to change it for the whole scope.

```
for ($x = 2; $x -le 255; $x++) {

    $ip = "172.30.218.$x"

    try {
        Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -IPAddress $ip -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Can't find $ip"
    }

}
```

Another option, if you don't care about the error, is `SilentlyContinue`:

```
for ($x = 2; $x -le 255; $x++) {
    $ip = "172.30.218.$x"
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -IPAddress $ip -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

See [`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847884.aspx) for more details about `ErrorAction` and `ErrorVariable`.